# ElasticSearch regexp query of a path

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

So far I've used a query that would match paths and get aggregations of those paths:

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "path.keyword": [
        "/api/v1.0/cc-dashboard/aggregated",
        "/api/v1.1/cc-dashboard/aggregated",
        "/api/v1.2/cc-dashboard/aggregated",
        "/api/v1.3/cc-dashboard/aggregated"
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": { ...
```

Since the only difference between the paths is the version number (which keeps changing) I thought about using `Regexp` query.
In a normal regex I would search for `\/api\/v1\.\d\/cc-dashboard\/aggregated`.
I know ElasticSearch uses different reserved characters for this and I've tried everything I know, but the search comes back without hits.
Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a couple of things to watch out for here. First make sure that `path.keyword` is actually of the type "keyword" or else you will have problem matching b/c you are actually trying to match against tokens and Elasticsearch will split on `/`. Second it doesn't look like Elasticsearch supports `\d` to escape for a digit, but it does allow `[0-9]`. Third to escape the `.` I had to use two backslashes `\\`.

So all together now:

```
PUT /stackoverflow
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "path.keyword": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /stackoverflow/_doc/1
{
  "path.keyword": "/api/v1.0/cc-dashboard/aggregated"
}

POST /stackoverflow/_doc/2
{
  "path.keyword": "/api/v1.1/cc-dashboard/aggregated"
}

POST /stackoverflow/_doc/3
{
  "path.keyword": "/api/not/cc-dashboard/aggregated"
}

GET /stackoverflow/_search

GET /stackoverflow/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "path.keyword": {
        "value": "/api/v1\\.[0-9]/cc-dashboard/aggregated"
      }
    }
  }
}

DELETE /stackoverflow
```